# Error al solicitar el refresh_token al integrar la API de Google Drive con Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, google-api, google-drive

Hace +4 días implementé el registro e ingreso a través de Google en mi aplicación de Laravel.

Cuando el usuario no tiene una cuenta entonces se la crea, pero cuando ya está registrado lo que hace es permitirle el acceso.

```
public function handleProviderGoogleCallback()
    {
      $auth_user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

        $user = User::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'email' => $auth_user->email
            ],
            [
                'refresh_token' => $auth_user->refreshToken,
                'name'  =>  $auth_user->name
            ]
        );

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('info', "Bienvenido " . $user->name); //
    }
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es cuando voy a acceder a la ruta para ver mis archivos. Ya que me sale este error.

[image: Error al ingresar a la ruta '/drive']

Todo lo hice siguiente este tutorial: https://quantizd.com/google-drive-client-api-with-laravel/

He intentado hablar con el autor, pero no es posible que me responda.

Agradezco la orientación. Muchas gracias

Comment: Deberias de tener una funcion de redireccion antes de la que muestras, podrias publicarlo.

Comment: @Shassain Esto es lo que tengo antes del método. Esto está dentro del controlador LoginController. Espero que puedas ayudarme y gracias


    `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }`


Este es mi método para redirigir

    `public function redirectToGoogleProvider()
    {
      |$parameters = ['access_type' => 'offline'];
        
      return Socialite::driver('google')->scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"])->with($parameters)->redirect();
    }`

(Perdona la forma en como se ve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude resolver el problema.

Lo que sucedió es que Socialite no me permitía obtener el `refresh_token` y por eso me enviaba un valor nulo. Por lo tanto cambié la línea    `'refresh_token' => $auth_user->refreshToken,` por `'refresh_token' => $auth_user->token,`...

Tuve que hacer eso porque solamente me devolvía el `token` que se usa para iniciar sesión. Después de cambiar eso me funcionó, y la logré consumir la API de Google Drive.

Comment: recuerda que si esta respuesta reolvió tu problema, debes marcarla como aceptada para que sirva de referencia a otros usuarios

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por recordarme eso lo de aceptar la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

estuve realizando tu curso sobre "Integrar la API de Google Drive con Laravel" y básicamente el origen del error que tienes es porque te falto colocar el campo refresh_token como atributo fillable en el modelo de usuarios para que puedas actualizar este campo con el metodo updateOrCreate.

```
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', "refresh_token"
    ];
```

Saludos!

Comment: si te das cuenta eso que mencionas ya existe en la respuesta del propio OP